# error ./node_modules/pino-pretty/lib/utils.js:7:23 Module not found: Can't resolve 'worker_threads'

Tags: reactjs, logging, next.js

I am facing this issue while implementing client-side logging using **PINO**; trying to do so using browser API.

```
import pino from 'pino';
import pinoBrowser from 'pino';
import pinoPretty from 'pino-pretty';
// import logger from '.';
import fs from 'fs';

// Configure Pino to use the desired log level and format
const logger1 = pino({
    level: 'info',
    prettyPrint: pinoPretty(),
});

// Enable Pino in the browser
pinoBrowser(logger1);

const logFileStream = fs.createWriteStream(
    'C:/Users/SSING106/starttwo-productionlot-frontend/docs/clientLog.txt'
);

// Create the pino logger and set the writable stream as the log destination
const logger = pino({}, logFileStream);

// Start logging
logger.info('Client-side log message');
export default logger1;
```

I am excepting the code to generate a file `clientLog.txt` in docs folder and log events into it.